# Logstash define field within a field

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

Is there a way grok can save a field from within an already-defined field?

I have the following filter:

```
grok {
  match => [ "message", "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]\s+\[%{DATA:homebridge_app}\]\s+%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}" ]
}
```

Which results in "log_message" being populated with things like:

```
Current temperature for Entryway Thermostat is: 20.5 C
Current humidity for Entryway Thermostat is: 60%
Current temperature for Entryway Thermostat is: 21 C
Current temperature for Entryway Thermostat is: 21.5 C
Current humidity for Entryway Thermostat is: 61%
```

and so on.  There can be other data in there, but the above are the lines I'm interested in.

I want to be able to use Kibana to plot humidity and temperature on charts against time, but I still want log_message to contain the full string as above.  Is there a way I can save the integers from the log_message field, without splitting that field in two?

Full stack I'm using is Filebeat->Logstash->Elasticsearch->Kibana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a second grok filter on the `log_message` field:

```
grok { 
    match => { "log_message" => [ 
        "%{NUMBER:humidity}%$", 
        "%{NUMBER:temperature} C$" 
    ] } }
}
```

See [the grok plugin documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-match):

> If you need to match multiple patterns against a single field, the
>   value can be an array of patterns
>
> ```
> filter {
>    grok {     
>       match => { "message" => [ "Duration: %{NUMBER:duration}", "Speed: %{NUMBER:speed}" ] } 
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for; thanks!  Of course, I also need to set break_on_match => false for this to work.

Comment: @RCross I did not know about this option. But I don't understand why you would need `break_on_match`, since if something match with the first pattern, it won't match with the second. Or perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: Sorry - I don’t know how to highlight commands in thiese comment boxes, so it may not have been clean, but the point is that it is set to ‘false’ to prevent Logstash aborting when the first match is true.  By default, Logstash will abort as soon as it sees a match.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-break_on_match

Comment: Thank you, I understand what the option does